# How do I get the path of a file using AppleScript?

Tags: file, path, applescript, filepath

I am trying to simply get the path of a file on the computer, and store it in a variable, using AppleScript. I have had a good look online, and I can't find anything. Please can anyone tell me how to do this task? Thanks.

Comment: You don't mention where or how you are wanting to use the file reference, so I'll just point you to the **AppleScript Language Guide**'s section on [Aliases and Files](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/conceptual/ASLR_fundamentals.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH218-SW28).

Comment: Thanks for your responses. I would like to use the path to use the "cd <path>" in the terminal

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to get a file reference, the easiest would be to use something like `choose file` or `choose folder`, which returns an alias:

```
set myVariable to (choose folder)
```

For a POSIX path to use in something like **Terminal**, an alias has a `POSIX path` property:

```
set myVariable to POSIX path of (choose folder)
```

Note that certain characters (such as spaces) have different meanings with commands in **Terminal**, so paths should be quoted:

```
set myVariable to quoted form of POSIX path of (choose folder)
```

These can be mixed as needed:

```
set theFolder to (choose folder with prompt "Choose a folder:")

tell application "Terminal"
  activate
  do script "cd " & quoted form of POSIX path of theFolder
end tell
```

You can also use the `log` statement in the **Script Editor** to show expression results and variable contents - see the [Mac Automation Scripting Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/MacAutomationScriptingGuide/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016239) for basic concepts.